# How can I get the text from Charsequence?

Tags: android

thats my Strings file:

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Name</string>
    <string name="vp_locations">Locations</string>
    <string name="vp_client_area">Client Area</string>
    <string name="vp_menu">Menu</string>
</resources>
```

And I would like to get programmatically all these strings, I created an array to get all the string values that I need:

```
private CharSequence[] tbTitles = {
        getResources().getText(R.string.vp_locations),
        getResources().getText(R.string.vp_client_area),
        getResources().getText(R.string.vp_menu),
};
```

Now I would like to know how can I get the values, when I do this:

```
textView.setText(tbTitles[0]);
```

The application crashes

I already to convert from charsequence to string, doing this:

```
textView.setText(tbTitle[0].toString());
```

But nothing seems to work. Can you guys tell me what am I doing wrong?

Log:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2436)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1374)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5398)
>                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:940)
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
>                                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                               at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:89)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:78)
>                                                                                               at
>   com.example.rd.app.Interface.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:36)
>                                                                                               at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
>                                                                                               at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1215)
>                                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2436) 
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157) 
>                                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1374) 
>                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
>                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5398) 
>                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:940) 
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756) 
>                                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Thank you.

Comment: If it crashes the please put the crash log. There might be different reason for crash, like `textView` is null.

Comment: Why do you have an array of `CharSequence[]` and not `string[]` when you want an array of strings? You can do `getResources().getString(resourceId)`

Comment: I already tried to use String[] but my app keeps crashing

Comment: Please see my answer. Your error has nothing to do with String conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call `getResources()` from a field initializer like you are doing in

```
private CharSequence[] tbTitles = {
    getResources().getText(R.string.vp_locations),
    getResources().getText(R.string.vp_client_area),
    getResources().getText(R.string.vp_menu),
};
```

At this moment context is not setup yet. Its done after calling `onCreate`.

Change your code like this

```
private CharSequence[] tbTitles = new CharSequence[3];
```

and add this in `onCreate`

```
tbTitles = new CharSequence[]{
    getResources().getText(R.string.vp_locations),
    getResources().getText(R.string.vp_client_area),
    getResources().getText(R.string.vp_menu),
};
```

And finally use the array like this

```
textView.setText(tbTitle[0].toString());
```

**Note:** If you are using this array in only one method then you can simply move the declaration inside that method.

Comment: Thank you, is working now, you just forgot to complete this line on create, tbTitles = new CharSequence[]{ ... }

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing unnecessary work.

You can declare an array in your xml file like this:

```
<string-array name="vp_arr">
    <item>Locations</item>
    <item>Client Area</item>
    <item>Menu</item>
</string-array>
```

Get it in your class:

```
String[] tbTitles= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.vp_arr);
```

And set it in your `TextView`:

```
textView.setText(tbTitles[0]);
```